# Laravel query with joins and multiple where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to execute this query:

```
select
    *
FROM
    users
    left join emails on users.id = emails.user_id
WHERE
    users.username = 'firstuser'
    and emails.emailType = 'Primary';
```

This is what I have but it gives me an error:

```
$user = User::where('username','firstuser')->with('emails')
                                          ->where('emailType','Primary')
                                          ->get();
```

The message indicates that the join is not being made:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emailType' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = firstuser and `emailType` = Primary)
```

Also, in my User.php model file in have a function emails():

```
public function emails()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('Email');
   }
```

In my Email.php model I have a user() function

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

I've tried a bunch of combinations but can't get both where conditions to work together.  I'd like to do this as one query and not two queries (get userid and then query email with the user_id)  Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: You need either `join` or combo of `whereHas` and `with`. What result you expect exactly? Btw `with` doesn't join tables, that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `where` for the `emails` relationship in a callback to `with()`, otherwise, Eloquent will think you're trying to look for the `emailType` field in the `users` table.

```
$user = User::with(['emails' => function($query){
    $query->where('emailType','Primary');    
}])->where('username','first user')
->get();
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  with() will not accept a closure as a parameter and errors with an expecting string but getting an object.

Comment: Try passing an array to `with()` key being the relationship, val being the callback.

Comment: This does work as you say...  Sorry that it took so long to get back to choosing it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work based on the comments above.  But, it isn't a very elegant solution as I defined the relationships in the model but the join kind of bypasses all of that to force the join.  Here is what worked...

```
$user = User::join('emails', 'users.id', '=', 'emails.user_id')
                    ->where('emailType','=','Primary')
                    ->where('username',$username)
                    ->get();
```

What is the point of defining the relationships in your model if they don't get used to join the tables when you want to query the model?  Perhaps I'm missing something.